# Windows Azure File Explorer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a windows Azure Based Web site that needs to import data from a file.  So it has a button that opens up the File Explorer.  However it explores my Local Pc's File System.  Now If I select the required file for Import the program returns that the file does not exists as it presumably looks at the azure file system.

Is there a C Drive on azure where I can add files and directories?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and clarify whether this website is running in the Azure Web Sites service, Azure Web Role (cloud service), or Azure Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using azure websites there is one nice little secret that where you can explore the files of your website and see more details on your website https://yourWebsiteName.scm.azurewebsites.net/

It will give you information a file explorer and other tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provision your Azure web site from your local file system you may use FTP client like Filezila. All information and settings for FTP may be found on Dashboard of your site in Azure portal.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-manage/

Comment: I don't think this answer's the OP question, which is asking about uploading files to the website, not deploying the website itself.

Comment: Additionally, there are multiple ways to update content of a web site (assuming the use of Azure Web Sites) from the local file system, not just ftp.